# Depth First Search Algorithm - counting connected components

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

Hi guys I have question and need help.Maybe it's offtopic but I've already posted it on Code Review but noones answers. I've written this using pseudocode, and I am stuck.I should examine if number of Vertices in one conected component is even. My idea is to implement DFS and to put one counter and then to check whether counter%2==0 is or not. My problem is I don't know where to put counter.
Let's say DFS: is main method.

G = (V,E) V- vertices, E-edges
s-start point(vertex)

```
DFS(G,s):
boolean result <-- false
Discovered[v] <-- false for all Vertices V(v)
DFS1(G,s)
if (DFS1(G,u) % 2==0)
result  <-- true


DFS1(G,u):
Discovered[u] <-- true
// counter ++            But where I should initialize it??
foreach Edge (v,u) incident to u
if !Discovered[v]
DFS1(G,v)`
```

Comment: In DFS1 sum values of all recursive calls to DFS1 and returns that value plus 1

Comment: Can you please explain me little bit more in detail, why value +1, and where do I initialize that sum? if i put it there int sum = 0 it will always be 0, because of recursive method. Maybe I don't understand this, but would appreciate if u could explain me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare counter inside `DFS1`, like so:

```
DFS1(G,u):
    Discovered[u] = true
    int counter = 1                     // Count actual node           
    foreach Edge (v,u) incident to u
        if !Discovered[v]
            counter += DFS1(G,v)        // Count descendant nodes
    return counter
```

Or declare the counter in a global scope and just increment it on each `DFS1` call:

```
int counter = 0

DFS(G,s):
    boolean result = false
    Discovered[v] = false for all Vertices V(v)
    DFS1(G,s)
    if (counter % 2 == 0)
        result = true

DFS1(G,u):
    Discovered[u] = true
    counter++
    foreach Edge (v,u) incident to u
        if !Discovered[v]
            DFS1(G,v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Any time you set `Discovered[u]` to `True`, and it isn't already `True`, then you have found a new connected vertex, and should increment your counter.

Since `DFS1` never returns anything, I'm not sure how helpful checking what it returns will be, especially since you check after calling it with a variable not know in that scope.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think I could do it like the guy before explained. it should work, i think.